# extending a list of lists by a single element

Tags: prolog

I am trying to solve the following question in ProLog. I am a beginner.

Define a predicate `extend` such that if `Xss` and `Yss` are lists of
lists then `extend(X, Xss, Yss)` holds if `Yss` can be obtained by adding the
element `X` to the end of every element in `Xss`, e.g

```
?- extend(g, [[e], [b, c, f], [k, h]], Yss).

Yss = [[e, g], [b, c, f, g], [k, h, g]]
```

I have attempted this with the following, but there is an error message :

```
extend(X, [], []).

extend(X, [[Firstxss,_] | Restxss], Yss) :-
    Firstxss is [Firstxss,_|X],
    Yss is  [Yss | [Firstxss,_]],        
    Xss is Restxss,
    extend(X, Xss, Yss).
```

I have input the following :

```
?- extend(g, [[e], [b, c, f], [k, h]], Yss).
```

and it returns :

```
false.
```

I think I have a valid input and I do not understand why it is returning as `false.`

Comment: `is` is for evaluating arithmetic, it should not be used for general unification.

Comment: I would say, start by biting off a smaller problem. Make `extend/3` work for a simple list and don't worry about the nested lists case yet. Once you have that, you can make it work for the nested case using `atom/1` or `is_list/1`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding to a list of lists in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50088052/adding-to-a-list-of-lists-in-prolog)

Comment: It really helps to define clearly what you are working with and what goal you are trying to achieve. Every element of your lists are lists of themselves. Your goal is to grab every element of `Xss`, then add `X` to the tail. To do this you must take every element out of their containing list `Xss` and create a new list `Yss` which has `[Element|X]` for each element of `Xss`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a singleton variable `X` here:

```
extend(X, [], []).
```

It would be better to say `extend(_, [], [])` because you never refer to X again. It's important to understand why this is the case. In Prolog, all the action happens because of relationships the variables are in. If the variable only appears in one place, it's not participating in any relationships, so it should be replaced with `_`. (If you make such a change and the code appears to be nonsense, stop and study it, because it always means you have misunderstood something.)

Second, `is/2` is for evaluating arithmetic expressions. There's no math going on in this: `Firstxss is [Firstxss,_|X]` so you have confused it with `=`. This is really a double whammy though, because `=` does *not* mean assign in Prolog, it means **unify**. So there is no real situation in Prolog where you are going to have `X = X+1` or anything like that, which is exactly the kind of thing yo'ure doing here, trying to reuse a variable for different purposes.

What does `Firstxss` mean in this clause? It looks like it is the first item in a nested list in the second argument in the head: in other words, if you called `extend(g, [[e], [b, c, f], [k, h]], Yss)`, then `Firstxss = e`. *The value of `Firstxss` can never change*. It can only be rebound in a recursive call. So when you immediately say `Firstxss is [Firstxss,_|X]`, what Prolog sees is `b = [b,_|<another var>]`. This does not unify and your predicate fails at this point. Say it advanced, somehow. You make the same mistake on the next line with `Yss`.

It would help to think about your problem relationally. You have the wrong base case too. What is your base case? It's the case where you have reached the end of the list, and what should you do? Append X. So this is your base case:

```
extend(X, [], [X]).
```

Now think about what you want to do in the other cases: you have a head and a tail. How do you extend? You extend the tail, and your result is the head appended to the extended tail. Try and write this clause yourself, it is not that difficult!

Once you have that, the machinery for extending nested lists is simple: you test the head to see if it is a list. If it is, recur on the head as well as the tail! Like so:

```
extend(X, [Y|Ys], Result) :-
  (is_list(Y) -> extend(X, Y, Y1) ; Y1 = Y),
  ... % use Y1 as Y in building the result
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to do the same thing with every element of the outer list, this is quite a beautiful task for `maplist/3`. You can use `append/3` to extend a list by an additional element like so:

```
?- append([1,2],[element],Z).
Z = [1, 2, element].
```

However, you'll want to have `append/3` with two lacking arguments in `maplist/3`, therefore it would be opportune to have the first argument appended to the second argument. To realize that, you could write an auxiliary predicate that calls `append/3` with the first two arguments flipped, e.g:

```
flippedappend(X,Y,Z) :-
   append(Y,X,Z).
```

Building on this, you could define the actual relation like so:

```
x_lists_extended(X,Xss,Yss) :-
   maplist(flippedappend([X]),Xss,Yss).
```

Your example query yields the desired result:

```
?- x_lists_extended(g, [[e], [b, c, f], [k, h]], Yss).
Yss = [[e, g], [b, c, f, g], [k, h, g]].
```

Note that you can also use this predicate the other way around:

```
?- x_lists_extended(X, Xss, [[e, g], [b, c, f, g], [k, h, g]]).
X = g,
Xss = [[e], [b, c, f], [k, h]] ;
false.
```